# How can I reduce the dimension of data, loaded through the flow_from_directory function of ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

Since I load my data (images) from the structured folders, I utilize the `flow_from_directory` function of the `ImageDataGenerator` class, which is provided by `Keras`. I've no issues while feeding this data to a `CNN` model. But when it comes to an `LSTM` model, getting the following error: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (64, 28, 28, 1)`. How can I reduce the dimension of the input data while reading it via `ImageDataGenerator` objects to be able to use an `LSTM` model instead of a `CNN`?

p.s. The shape of the input images is `(28, 28)` and they are `grayscale`.

```
train_valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.2)

train_gen = train_valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=TRAIN_IMAGES_PATH,
    target_size=(28, 28),
    color_mode='grayscale',
    batch_size=64,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True,
    subset='training'
)
```

**Update:** The LSTM model code:

```
inp = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
inp = Lambda(lambda x: squeeze(x, axis=-1))(inp)  # from 4D to 3D
x = LSTM(num_units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout, activation=activation_fn, return_sequences=True)(inp)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dense(128, activation=activation_fn)(x)
output = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001))(x)

model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you start feeding your network with 4D data like your images in order to have the compatibility with `ImageDataGenerator` and then you have to reshape them in 3D format for LSTM.

These are the possibilities:

with only one channel you can simply squeeze the last dimension

```
inp = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
x = Lambda(lambda x: tf.squeeze(x, axis=-1))(inp) # from 4D to 3D
x = LSTM(32)(x)
```

if you have multiple channels (this is the case of RGB images or if would like to apply a RNN after a Conv2D) a solution can be this

```
inp = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
x = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(inp)
x = Reshape((28,28*32))(x)  # from 4D to 3D
x = LSTM(32)(x)
```

the fit can be computed as always with `model.fit_generator`

---

UPDATE: model review

```
inp = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
x = Lambda(lambda x: squeeze(x, axis=-1))(inp)  # from 4D to 3D
x = LSTM(32, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout, activation=activation_fn, return_sequences=False)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dense(128, activation=activation_fn)(x)
output = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001))(x)

model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=output)
model.summary()
```

pay attention when you define inp variable (don't overwrite it)

set return_seq = False in LSTM in order to have 2D output